# 2d ZigZag movement in XNA/Monogame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I have a ball which is moving in Zigzag manner.Here is the code for that-

```
foreach (TouchLocation touchlevel1 in touchCollection1)
        {
            if ((touchlevel1.State == TouchLocationState.Released))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count % 2 == 1)
        {
            position.X -= 0.25f * gametime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
            position.Y -= 0.25f * gametime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;

        }
        if (count % 2 == 0)
        {
            position.X += 0.25f * gametime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
            position.Y -= 0.25f * gametime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
        }
```

But I need help on camera codes.Basically what is the logic for Zigzag movement in XNA/Monogame in 2d.

I have found some help here,but wondering how to do in XNA codes-

https://github.com/Thipi/SimpleBallGame/blob/master/cameraFollow.cs

Comment: What is the exact question? You want the camera to follow the ZigZag Movement? Like having the ball in the center?

Comment: @PavelSlesinger-Looking similar to this,I hope I am in good direction.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PyXYBkvZY3k

Comment: Its easy doable with a few lines of code. You need to generate a view matrix like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662876/xna-2d-camera-how-to-lock-center-it-to-an-animated-sprite

Comment: Is this a Unity Question or MonoGame/XNA question?

Comment: @Strom-Its a monogame question